# adding files to an executable jar at runtime

Tags: java, executable-jar

I need to add files to an executable jar at runtime(based on the user input).

My application creates `.java` and `.xml` files at runtime which needs to be added to the project so that they can be further used, it works fine when I use the project in eclipse. But doesn't work with  executable jar, as the files are not addded to it.

What I have found is executable jar gets locked when created and can't be changed at runtime, is there any way to deal with this problem other than reading files from external path (like user home directory)?

Comment: Jarfiles are zip files, and zip files aren't really modifiable in place. You might hack something out that works, but the more usual approach is to write to a local filesystem.

Comment: See implementation of hot reload (hot deploy, hot swap, etc.). You can make custom class loader. And, best solution, you can make good design pattern.

Comment: Why do you need to add files in the jar? You can place them somewhere in a tmp dir and use them or create a custom separate resource.jar and place them in the file.